# How to load data from Cassandra into ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, logstash, kibana

[image: this is the error log of logstash]I have installed Cassandra 3.11.3 in my ubuntu virtual machine. I have also installed the ELK(elasticsearch, logstash, kibana).

What is the way using which I can visualize the Cassandra data into Kibana using the ELK. Please let me know the detail configurations that i will need to do in order to get data from Cassandra database into the Kibana dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I did the similar thing using Kafka, where I used below structure:

```
Cassandra -> Confluent Kafka -> Elastic search.
```

Its pretty easy to do as connectors are provided by Confluent.

But if you only need to visualize the data , you can try Banana which gels well with Cassandra.

Note: Banana is forked version of Kibana.

Se

Comment: i have added the snapshot of logstash log file. can you please help me solve this error.

Comment: Please don't mix 2 issues here, also I dont see any error in logs snapshot.